# Magento showing errors in developer mode

Tags: magento2, error, exception, interceptor, vendor

I have enabled developer and it's showing me following errors :

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/TemplateMonster/FilmSlider/Block/Widget/FilmSlider.php on line 105

Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/TemplateMonster/FilmSlider/Block/Widget/FilmSlider.php on line 105
<pre>#1 TemplateMonster\FilmSlider\Block\Widget\FilmSlider->loaderDimensions('{"slider_id":"5"...') called at [generated/code/TemplateMonster/FilmSlider/Block/Widget/FilmSlider/Interceptor.php:63]
#2 TemplateMonster\FilmSlider\Block\Widget\FilmSlider\Interceptor->loaderDimensions('{"slider_id":"5"...')
#3 call_user_func_array(array(&TemplateMonster\FilmSlider\Block\Widget\FilmSlider\Interceptor#000000005e8a245b00000000218919f2#, 'loaderDimensions'), array('{"slider_id":"5"...')) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:82]
#4 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->__call('loaderDimensions', array('{"slider_id":"5"...')) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php/Interceptor.php:37]
#5 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->__call('loaderDimensions', array('{"slider_id":"5"...')) called at [app/code/TemplateMonster/FilmSlider/view/frontend/templates/widget/filmslider/default.phtml:5]
#6 include('/opt/bitnami/app...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:59]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(&TemplateMonster\FilmSlider\Block\Widget\FilmSlider\Interceptor#000000005e8a245b00000000218919f2#, '/opt/bitnami/app...', array('csp' => &Magento\Csp\Helper\InlineUtil#000000005e8a241e00000000218919f2#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->___callParent('render', array(&TemplateMonster\FilmSlider\Block\Widget\FilmSlider\Interceptor#000000005e8a245b00000000218919f2#, '/opt/bitnami/app...', array('csp' => &Magento\Csp\Helper\InlineUtil#000000005e8a241e00000000218919f2#))) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&TemplateMonster\FilmSlider\Block\Widget\FilmSlider\Interceptor#000000005e8a245b00000000218919f2#, '/opt/bitnami/app...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->___callPlugins('render', array(&TemplateMonster\FilmSlider\Block\Widget\FilmSlider\Interceptor#000000005e8a245b00000000218919f2#, '/opt/bitnami/app...', array()), array(array('csp_helper_plugi...'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php/Interceptor.php:26]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->render(&TemplateMonster\FilmSlider\Block\Widget\FilmSlider\Interceptor#000000005e8a245b00000000218919f2#, '/opt/bitnami/app...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:271]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/opt/bitnami/app...') called at [generated/code/TemplateMonster/FilmSlider/Block/Widget/FilmSlider/Interceptor.php:180]
#13 TemplateMonster\FilmSlider\Block\Widget\FilmSlider\Interceptor->fetchView('/opt/bitnami/app...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:301]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1100]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1104]
#16 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:674]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [app/code/TemplateMonster/FilmSlider/Block/Widget/FilmSlider.php:127]
#18 TemplateMonster\FilmSlider\Block\Widget\FilmSlider->toHtml() called at [generated/code/TemplateMonster/FilmSlider/Block/Widget/FilmSlider/Interceptor.php:89]
#19 TemplateMonster\FilmSlider\Block\Widget\FilmSlider\Interceptor->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:566]
#20 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('RiKBubYQVryPL12f...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:542]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('RiKBubYQVryPL12f...') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('RiKBubYQVryPL12f...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:497]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('RiKBubYQVryPL12f...', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#24 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('RiKBubYQVryPL12f...', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:594]
#25 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:544]
#26 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#27 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('content') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:497]
#28 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#29 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('content', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:594]
#30 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:544]
#31 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#32 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:497]
#33 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#34 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:594]
#35 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('columns', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:544]
#36 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('columns') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#37 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('columns') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:497]
#38 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('columns', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#39 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('columns', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:594]
#40 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.content', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:544]
#41 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.content') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#42 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.content') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:497]
#43 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.content', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#44 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.content', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:594]
#45 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:544]
#46 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#47 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:497]
#48 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#49 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:594]
#50 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper.out...', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:544]
#51 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper.out...') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#52 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper.out...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:497]
#53 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper.out...', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#54 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper.out...', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:594]
#55 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:544]
#56 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#57 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:497]
#58 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#59 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:963]
#60 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#61 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('getOutput', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#62 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#63 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', array(), array(array('layout-model-cac...'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:494]
#64 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php:258]
#65 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000005e8a22b900000000218919f2#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php:171]
#66 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000005e8a22b900000000218919f2#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#67 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000005e8a22b900000000218919f2#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#68 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000005e8a22b900000000218919f2#) called at [app/code/Magezon/Core/Plugin/View/Result/Layout.php:24]
#69 Magezon\Core\Plugin\View\Result\Layout->aroundRenderResult(&Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor#000000005e8a260500000000218919f2#, &Closure#000000005e8a230800000000218919f2#, &Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000005e8a22b900000000218919f2#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#70 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000005e8a22b900000000218919f2#) called at [app/code/Zemez/Amp/Model/Plugin/Framework/Controller/ResultInterfacePlugin.php:95]
#71 Zemez\Amp\Model\Plugin\Framework\Controller\ResultInterfacePlugin->aroundRenderResult(&Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor#000000005e8a260500000000218919f2#, &Closure#000000005e8a230800000000218919f2#, &Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000005e8a22b900000000218919f2#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#72 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000005e8a22b900000000218919f2#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#73 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000005e8a22b900000000218919f2#), NULL) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php:130]
#74 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000005e8a22b900000000218919f2#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:120]
#75 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#76 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#77 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#000000005e8a22a000000000218919f2#) called at [index.php:39]
</pre>
```

does anyone know how to solve them
???

code in line:

```
public function loaderDimensions($jsonParams)
    {
        $params = json_decode($jsonParams, true);
        $loader = [];

        if ($params['aspectRatio'] == -1) {
            $loader['height'] = $params['height'];
            $loader['padding'] = 0;
            $loader['position'] = 'no-abs';
        } elseif ($params['aspectRatio'] != 0) {
            $loader['height'] = 'auto';
            $loader['padding'] = 100 / $params['aspectRatio']; //105 line
            $loader['position'] = 'abs';
        }

        return $loader;
    
    }
```

Thank in advance

Comment: apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/TemplateMonster/FilmSlider/Block/Widget/FilmSlider.php  line 105 please attach this line of code

Comment: code is attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line no. 105 Replace with this code :-

```
$loader['padding'] = number_format(100 / $params['aspectRatio']);
```

Comment: trying thanks for suggestion

Comment: Resolved issue ???

Comment: No  still same errors

Comment: 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (LogicException): Could not create an acl object: Invalid Document 
Element 'resource': The attribute 'title' is required but missing.
Line: 12


Exception #0 (LogicException): Could not create an acl object: Invalid Document 
Element 'resource': The attribute 'title' is required but missing.
Line: 12

Comment: <pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Acl\Builder\Proxy->getAcl() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Auth/Session.php:229]
#2 Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session->processLogin() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Auth.php:165]

Comment: any suggestions

Comment: i think its another error

Comment: try to php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: done that also  but still same

Comment: any error in this step ??

Comment: No php bin/magento setup:di:compile runs smoothly

Comment: If I enable the default mode then the error is gone